# Default boot partition osx

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

I installed osx Yosemite along with mavericks. My MacBook was booting into Yosemite by default. In the system preference I change to target disk mode. Now when I restart my MacBook asks for a password (I think this is yosemite ui) it doesn't take my default password and now I don't know how to boot into some partition. I tried holding cmd r cmd s and none of the mode boots. All I get is password prompt. I am now posting from my iPad :( kindly help me

Comment: Gray screen with just a lock icon and password field. Looks like file vault screen. I once had FileVault enabled in mavericks but then disabled it long back.

Comment: :( yes the same image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing something like this:

[image]

then you have a firmware password set.

There are 2 ways to go forward:

[1](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/disablefirmwarepwp.html):

- Insert your Mac OS X Install DVD into the optical drive of the Mac.
- Restart the Mac using the Startup Manager: press and hold the Option key as soon as you hear the startup tone.
- The Firmware Password prompt appears. Type the firmware password for the computer, then click the arrow or press Return. If you typed the firmware password correctly, the screen will change to show available startup disks, including Macintosh HD and the Mac OS X Install DVD.
- Click the Mac OS X Install DVD. Then either click the arrow beneath it or press Return. - - The Mac begins to start up form the disc.
- When prompted, choose your language, then either click the arrow or press Return. After a short time, the Install Mac OS X window appears.
- In the menu bar, choose Utilities > Firmware Password Utility…. The Firmware Password Utility will load: be patient, as it loads slowly.
- In the Firmware Password Utility window, click New.
- In the Firmware Password Utility window, deselect Require password to start this computer from another source.
- Click OK. The Firmware Password Utility window displays text indicating that the changes will be implemented after a restart.
- Click Quit. Focus returns to the Install Mac OS X window.
- Quit (Command-Q) the Installer. Choose Restart when prompted.
- After restarting, firmware password protection is disabled. Eject the Mac OS X Install DVD from the optical drive and store it properly.

2: [Go to an Apple Genius Bar:](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3554?)

> Only Apple Retail Stores or Apple Authorized Service Providers can unlock computers protected by a firmware password.
>
> > If you can't remember the firmware password for your Mac, schedule a service appointment with either an Apple Retail Store or an Apple Authorized Service Provider.  If you plan to visit an Apple Retail Store, please make a reservation (available in some countries only).

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> key while you turn your computer on.  That should bring you to a boot list where you can select Mavericks.

Comment: I tried but it asks for password and doesn't show list

Comment: If it's asking for a password when you're option-booting, then you have a firmware password set.  This is a very bad situation to be in if you don't know what that password is!